# RSA decrypting data in C# (.NET 3.5) which was encrypted with openssl in php 5.3.2

Tags: c#, .net, php, cryptography, rsa

Maybe someone can clear me up. I have been surfing on this a while now.

### Step #1: Create a root certificate

*Key generation on unix*

```
1) openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout privatekey.pem -out mycert.pem

2) openssl rsa -in privatekey.pem -pubout -out publickey.pem

3) openssl pkcs12 -export -out mycertprivatekey.pfx -in mycert.pem -inkey privatekey.pem -name "my certificate"
```

---

### Step #2: Does root certificate work on php: YES

*PHP side*

I used the publickey.pem to read it into php:

```
$publicKey = "file://C:/publickey.pem";
$privateKey = "file://C:/privatekey.pem";
$plaintext = "123";

openssl_public_encrypt($plaintext, $encrypted, $publicKey);
$transfer = base64_encode($encrypted);
openssl_private_decrypt($encrypted, $decrypted, $privateKey);

echo $decrypted;  // "123"
```

OR

```
$server_public_key = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents("C:\publickey.pem"));
// rsa encrypt
openssl_public_encrypt("123", $encrypted, $server_public_key);

//and the privatekey.pem to check if it works:
openssl_private_decrypt($encrypted, $decrypted, openssl_get_privatekey(file_get_contents("C:\privatekey.pem")));

echo $decrypted;  // "123"
```

Coming to the conclusion, that encryption/decryption works fine on the php side with these openssl root certificate files.

---

### Step #3: Does root certificate work on .NET: YES

*C# side*

In same manner I read the keys into a .net C# console program:

```
X509Certificate2 myCert2 = null;
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = null;

try
{
    myCert2 = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\mycertprivatekey.pfx", "password");
    rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)myCert2.PrivateKey;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.writeln(e.message); // because I left a blank catch block, I did not realize there was an exception! I missed the password for the certificate.
}

byte[] test = {Convert.ToByte("123")};

string t = Convert.ToString(rsa.Decrypt(rsa.Encrypt(test, false), false));
```

Coming to the point, that encryption/decryption works fine on the c# side with these openssl root certificate files.

---

### Step #4: Enrypt in php and Decrypt in .NET: YES

*PHP side*

```
$onett = "123"
....
openssl_public_encrypt($onett, $encrypted, $server_public_key);
$onettbase64 = base64_encode($encrypted);
```

copy - paste $onettbase64 ("LkU2GOCy4lqwY4vtPI1JcsxgDgS2t05E6kYghuXjrQe7hSsYXETGdlhzEBlp+qhxzTXV3pw+AS5bEg9CPxqHus8fXHOnXYqsd2HL20QSaz+FjZee6Kvva0cGhWkFdWL+ANDSOWRWo/OMhm7JVqU3P/44c3dLA1eu2UsoDI26OMw=") into c# program:

*C# side*

```
byte[] transfered_onett = rsa.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String("LkU2GOCy4lqwY4vtPI1JcsxgDgS2t05E6kYghuXjrQe7hSsYXETGdlhzEBlp+qhxzTXV3pw+AS5bEg9CPxqHus8fXHOnXYqsd2HL20QSaz+FjZee6Kvva0cGhWkFdWL+ANDSOWRWo/OMhm7JVqU3P/44c3dLA1eu2UsoDI26OMw="), false);

string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(transfered_onett); // "123"
```

No problems.

Comment: BTW, I think you meant .NET 3.5. There's no C# 3.5.

Comment: that's correct, I meant .NET 3.5

Comment: Ok, so you've got 2 samples ending with 'works fine', so what is the actual question?

Comment: Are you sure you are correctly reading in the private key on the .NET side? All the X509Certificate2 constructors that read PFX files *also* require a password argument.

Comment: @GregS you are right! That was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use one of the X509Certificate2 constructors that are designed for PFX (aka pkcs#12) files. These take a password argument. In your original example, you were silently swallowing all exceptions so you missed the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is solved. I had forgotten to fill the catch block so I did not realize there was an exception with the certificate reading on the c# side. With read certificate, decryption is no problem now.

Comment: I can't ;) I have to wait two days :D Although GregS found the problem, I had solved it with another friend just minutes ago but I will mark GregS solution.